# How to organize page layout using Box?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm developing a web app using React and Material UI. I would like a layout with two Boxes inside a third one. The Box at the bottom should be just high enough to hold its contents. The Box at the top, must occupy all the space remaining inside the third Box.

I'm trying to do this with the code that follows. However, it's not working. Can someone help me?

```
<Box
                                component="main"
                                sx={{
                                    height: '100vh',
                                    overflow: 'auto',
                                    justifyContent: "center",
                                    display: 'flex',
                                    flexWrap: 'wrap',
                                    alignContent: 'top',
                                    marginTop: '50px', bgcolor: "green"
                                }}
                            >
    
    <Box sx={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    {/* Content here */}
    </Box>
    <Box sx={{
            minWidth: '100%',
            bgcolor: "secondary.main",
            marginTop: "40px",
            marginBottom: "0px", 
            paddingBottom: "0px", paddingTop: "40px", 
            paddingLeft: "40px", paddingRight: "40px"
        }}>
        {/* Content here */}
    </Box>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `display: 'flex'` on your main box this is pretty easy to achieve. All you have to add is `alignContent: 'space-between'` and that will align the two boxes to the vertical edges of the main container/Box.

So your code should look like:

```
<Box
      component="main"
      sx={{
        height: '100vh',
        overflow: 'auto',
        justifyContent: "center",
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        alignContent: 'top',
        marginTop: '50px',
        bgcolor: "green",
        alignContent: 'space-between'
      }}>
      <Box sx={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        {/* Content here */}
      </Box>
      <Box sx={{
        minWidth: '100%',
        bgcolor: "secondary.main",
        marginTop: "40px 0 0 0",
        padding: '40px 40px 0 40px'
      }}>
        {/* Content here */}
      </Box>
    </Box>
```

Now, to your point *"The Box at the top, must occupy all the space remaining inside the third Box"* the remaining space is technically reserved for the top box as you add more content to it while the bottom box is aligned to the bottom of the screen.

As a reference, read more about the [align-content property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container#aligning_content_on_the_cross_axis_%E2%80%94_the_align-content_property)